# I do not receive email from a .media domain

Tags: email, dns, media

I am using Gmail (the paid version) and I cannot receive mails from a .media domain.

The company that I am emailing does get my emails, but when they respond it does not arrive in my inbox/spambox.

Next to this, there is no error mail or bounce mail. So I am really wondering what I can do in order to receive mails from person@company.media domains. I already added people as a contact person.

Comment: Could you obtain log entries generated at sender side?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the correct mx records are in place?

Also you can contact google support for this issue.

Comment: I will try to contact support. MX is all good. I have only problems with .media mailaccounts